# for_each subnet ids in GCP with terraform module.subnets is object with 1 attribute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, foreach, terraform

I have a problem I have a module in terraform with try to create subnets in the currency network, when I try to get the ids from subnets array module, it simply don't work:

```
module "subnets" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/network/google//modules/subnets-beta"
  version = "5.0.0"
  for_each = local.subnets
  project_id   = var.project_id
  network_name = google_compute_network.default.self_link
  subnets = [for subnet in var.subnets : {
    description               = "Subnet on ${var.region} with 192.168.1.0/28"
    subnet_name               = format("sn-%s-%s-%s", "test", "fr", replace("192.168.1.0/28", "/\\.|\\//", "-"))
     subnet_ip                 = "192.168.1.0/28"
     subnet_region             = var.region
     role                      = "ACTIVE"  #== "regional-managed-proxy" ? "ACTIVE" : null
     }
  ]

}
```

try to get those ids:

```
module "package_mirror" {
   source = "./modules/package_mirror"
   for_each = {for index, subnet in module.subnets:  index => subnet}  
   project_id = var.project_id  
   region = "europe-west3"
   network_self_link = google_compute_network.default.self_link
   #index  = index(local.groups_sub_west3, each.value)
   subnets = tolist(each.value.id) #here the issue
   depends_on = [module.subnets ]
}
```

`Output:

```
frangcpaprend@cloudshell:~/poc_subnets$ terraform plan 
google_compute_network.default: Refreshing state... [id=projects/eighth-network-376613/global/networks/corelight-network]
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 49, in module "package_mirror":
│   49:   subnets = tolist(each.value.id)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 1 attribute "subnets"
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
╵`
```

frangcpaprend@cloudshell:~/poc_subnets$

Can you help me? Our know a price? I think this is a Devil trick.

try this for_each = {for index, subnet in module.subnets:  index => subnet}

and expecting get a list of ids : subnets = tolist(each.value.id)

Answer (score 1):

I think in the `package_mirror` module, the `for_each` returns a `Map`, in this cas case you can retrieve a value of an entry in the map as follow :

```
module "package_mirror" {
   source = "./modules/package_mirror"
   for_each = {for index, subnet in module.subnets:  index => subnet}  
   project_id = var.project_id  
   region = "europe-west3"
   network_self_link = google_compute_network.default.self_link
   #index  = index(local.groups_sub_west3, each.value)
   subnets = tolist(each.value["id"]) #I used each.value["field_name"]
   depends_on = [module.subnets ]
}
```